# Point within a Square C++

Tags: c++, parsing, input, geometry, coordinates

I'm trying to solve this particular problem using c++.

Problem:
Given a set of (x,y) coordinates on a Euclidean geometric plane, and a set of four (x,y) coordinates that define a square, I need to determine if all the points are contained within the defined square. Points that are found on the sides of the square or the corners of the square count as points in the square. The square is not necessarily parallel to the axes.

The input is a bit interesting and there are no prompts, just strictly typing in coordinates.

Input: A set of comma separated (x,y) coordinates, which are separated by spaces. 
The first four coordinates define the corners of a square (in no particular order) and the remainder of the comma separated coordinates will be the points.

So for example:
0,0 0,5 5,0 5,5 1,1 2,2 3,3
(Defines a square with corners (0,0)/(0,5)/(5,0)/(5,5) and three points (1,1)/(2,2)/(3,3))
I'm assuming the best course of action is to use getline and then parse the input.

Output is true or false if at least one point is outside the square.

It's been difficult trying to wrap my head around this and I can really appreciate help.

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you attempt something on your own.

Comment: What exactly have you got problems with? Reading the input?

Comment: There are probably more direct approaches, but one way is to translate and rotate the whole thing so that a corner of the square is at (0,0) and has its base be parallel to the X axis. From there, the inside/outside check is trivial.

Comment: Mostly input, I tried using determinants to figure out the math behind it.

Comment: Well, show the code you've got so far and outline the problems.

Comment: Parsing is one problem and a point-in-polygon test is a separate problem.  Please ask the questions separately and provide more details... code that you've written so far perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input I recommend looking up [Inserter interators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_inserter/).

Something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

class point
{
public:
  friend
  std::istream& 
  operator>>(std::istream& in, point& data)
  { 
    char separator;
    in >> data.m_x >>separator >>data.m_y ;
  }

  friend
  std::ostream&
  operator<<(std::ostream& out, point& data)
  { 
    out<< "("<<data.m_x<<','<<data.m_y<<")";
    return out;
  }
private:
  double m_x, m_y;
};

int
main  (int ac, char **av)
{

  std::vector<point> buffer;

  std::copy( 
            std::istream_iterator<point>(std::cin), 
            std::istream_iterator<point>( ),
        std::back_inserter(buffer)); // copies all data into buffer

  std::cout<<"buffer size = "<<buffer.size()<<std::endl;

  for(size_t i=0;i<buffer.size();++i){
    std::cout<<buffer[i]<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
./a.out
1,2 3,4 5,6 q
buffer size = 3
(1,2)
(3,4)
(5,6)
```

Comment: Thanks, this really got me going in the right direction.  I'm going to study some more on Inserter interators with that link.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble parsing the code, show what you've got so far. When your parsing works, here is an awesome solution to determining if a point is inside of any polygon:
http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Comment: Thanks, I've been using math formulas to figure it out but this is a very cool alternative as well.